# How can I change my OS's identifier in order to spoof another OS?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I want to install the MSIX version of (the new) Microsoft Edge Canary, however, it appears to be only installable on a HoloLens or Xbox system currently (although I imagine that it can on Windows 10 X too). Therefore, I want to change the identifier of my Windows 10 Pro installation in order to make the installer think that my operating system is a valid one.

I've looked in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion, and that seems like a good place to start.

Also, do not worry about the integrity of my installation of Windows 10 Pro, for I will try this first in some form of sandboxed environment such as a virtual machine.

Comment: I strongly suspect even if you trick the installer into thinking you are running HoloLens (which has an incompatible processor) or Windows 10 X (which has an incompatible processor) you are going to find that you are unable to run the program. `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` does not contain the key you are looking for.  There are more efficient ways to determine what platform you are on.  You can install the Windows 10 X emulator and install Edge there.

Comment: Thank you, @Ramhound. I had not thought of that; incompatible processors explains why the package is limited to such proprietary hardware.